# Swiftui Picker with protocol type - Compiler is unable to type-check this expression

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols, swiftui-picker

Given this Struct who conforms to `Relationable` protocol

```
struct RomanticRelation: Relationable{
    
    typealias Relationship = RomanticRelationType
    typealias Relation = RomanticRelation
    var nickname: String
    var lastInteracted: Date
    var relationship: RomanticRelationType = .couple //Enum type

}
```

---

```
protocol Relationable {
    
    associatedtype Relation
    associatedtype Relationship:Hashable  //Enum
    var nickname:String { get set }
    var lastInteracted:Date { get set }
    var relationship:Relationship { get set }
    var typicalInterests:[String] { get }
    var interests:[String] { get set }
    
}
```

And this `Published` variable in a ViewModel who conforms to `ObservableObject`

```
class RelationsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selectedRelation: any Relationable = PersonalRelation()

}
```

the `relationship` variable is a `Enum` who conforms to `CaseIterable` and `Hashable`

---

```
enum RomanticRelationType:Hashable, CaseIterable {
   

    case couple, married, engaged
    
    var title: String {
        
        switch self {
        case .couple:
            return "Couple"
        case .married:
            return "Married"
        case .engaged:
            return "Engaged"
        }
    }
    var priority: Int {
        switch self {
        case .couple:
            return 3
        case .engaged:
            return 2
        case .married:
            return 1
        }
    }
    
}
```

If I got 3 structs who conforms to the protocol with each one this variable (relationship), I want to assign it to the `Picker` selection instead of making 3 `Picker`

when assigning a known type(String) from the protocol  its working

```
 TextField("Nickname", text: $relationsVM.selectedRelation.nickname)
                                .modifier(TextFieldModifier(width: 250, height: 30))
                                .padding(.top)
```

---

BUT, with the picker it wont work

```
Picker("Type", selection: $relationsVM.selectedRelation.relationship) {
    //ForEach got a simple string array
ForEach(relationsVM.allRelationships) { relationType in 
Text(relationType)
   }
  }.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

The compiler is unable to type check and compile I know it is because of the `selected` parameter of the picker, maybe need to force cast the type somewhere?

Comment: Seems to me the problem might be that you are assigning a property of a published value to the `selection`, not the published value itself. Another issue I can imagine is that `Relationable` is a protocol, so the compiler can't be sure it is going to be a value type, which is required for a binding.

Comment: I would refactor your `RelationsViewModel` (or add and additional view model), and have a published property of `RomanticRelationType`, which is a value type and perfect for a `Picker`.

Comment: there is 3 type of enums for each struct, that's why I declared each property in their respective struct. I don't want to declare it as a standalone. I would need 3 property for each enum. also why its working for the nickname property but not with the relationship property? @vicegax

Comment: nickname is type `String`, which is a value type. `Relationship` is an `associatedtype` and not a value type (could be a class or other reference type).

Comment: 1 published property for each enum could be a way to go; another option could be making all your enums have a `rawValue` (an `Int` for example), and your view model contain a published property of an `Int`. You would additionally need another published property to know which one of the enums is the current one.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. But `any` does not work well with SwiftUI view you usually need concrete types

Comment: I shared a lot of code. why minimal? imagine you got x structs who got the same properties, you want to make 1 view for all the 3  and assigning the Published property to it, not duplicating code and making multiples views. @loremipsum

Comment: @vicegax I got associated values in one of the enum. making it with rawValue is not ideal.maybe creating the entire ``Content`` View generic ?

Comment: If a minimal example isn't worth your time why would it be worth it for anyone else? Like I sad your issue is likely with `any` you need a concrete type

Comment: When declaring the ``Published`` variable of type protocol  I got  ```Use of protocol 'Relationable' as a type must be written 'any Relationable'``` so it's needed to apply the ``any``

Comment: SwiftUI usually only works with Concrete types not existential, `any` == existential

Comment: how did you conclude that I don't have time to reproduce a minimal example? @loremipsum what's your suggested solution? telling me SwiftUI usually only works with x y z is not an answer to the problem. ``any`` is needed as it's a ``protocol``

Comment: I haven't written a solution, if you had provided a minimal example I would have already provided an answer in the answer section. These are just observations. you don't use `any` when dealing with protocols/generics that are passed as concretes.

Comment: @David.C Answering your question: adding more generics would unfortunately not help. As I have mentioned above and also was suggested by _lorem ipsum_  the problem is SwiftUI bindings need to have a value type, which are concrete types. Protocols and Generics can't be used.

Comment: Provide minimum code that compiles

Comment: @user1046037 I'm asking a question regarding  a code that wont compile, and you ask me to provide a code that compile. if you understood the logic answer the question, if not, don't.

Comment: Where have you defined PersonalRelation? Portions of the code seem to be missing